# In JavaScript, what's the correct syntax for the OR operator within a conditional statement? What am I missing?

Tags: javascript, operators, conditional-statements

I'm unsure how to word this exactly, what I would like to know is how does the OR operator function exactly within a conditional?

Here is the sample code, it just counts the B's in the string.

```js
var countB = function(s) {
  var counter = 0;
  for (var c = 0; c < s.length; c++) {
    if (s.charAt(c) == "B") {
      counter++;
    }
  }
  return counter;
}
console.log(countB("Butter balls are BBBbBBUttERRYY!"));
```

Now, When I run this it runs fine but when I change the if condition to

```
s.charAt(c) == "B" || "b"
```

It counts all of the characters.

Why is it doing this exactly, what is the correct syntax?

Comment: `s.charAt(c) == "B" || s.charAt(c) == "b"`

Comment: or more simply `/b/i.test(s.charAt(c))`

Comment: Is there a "/b/i.test" example for that kind of use on the MDN? I'm reading Eloquent JS currently.

Answer (score 5):

`s.charAt(c) == "B" || "b"` is essentially equal to `(s.charAt(c) == "B") || ("b")`

Whenever the check for `s.charAt(c) == "B"` fails, the `"b"` value is truthy and it succeeds.

The correct syntax would be `s.charAt(c) == "B" || s.charAt(c) == "b"`

Comment: This still doesn't explain why the edited code counts all of the characters  expect for the exclamatory mark versus just the B or b though and why is that the correct syntax?

Comment: That is just the way conditionals work in javascript -- see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators.

Comment: @AndrewPower: Your loop is excluding the last character because of the `c < s.length - 1`. It should just be `c < s.length`

Comment: You're missing what I'm trying to explain, the "b" itself turns out to come out as true from what I now understand. So strings that are not empty result in true no matter what then, and that's why it's counting all of the letters because of the b is always going to be true. I see what you're saying now but you could of been a bit more descriptive and stated that filled strings come out to be truthful and that the precedence of the comparison operator trumps the or operator. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to count all 'b's(both upper and lower case), then

> **s.charAt(c) == "B" || s.charAt(c) == "b"**

is the right way to do it.

> **s.charAt(c) == "B" || "b"**

counts all characters because, '==' has higher precedence than logical operator, which means, JS reads your expression as:

> **(s.charAt(c) == "B") || ("b")**

and inside an if "b" comes out as true, so, your statement becomes

> **(s.charAt(c) == "B") || true**

and your whole expression turns out to be true.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an additional alternative that is a single compare operation and will return true if your char is upper or lower case:

```
s.charAt(c).toLowerCase() == "b"
"B".toLowerCase() == "b" //true
"b".toLowerCase() == "b" //true
```

Answer (score 0):

What happen here in `s.charAt(c) == "B" || "b"` is,

JavaScript engine first evaluate the `s.charAt(c) == "B"` according to the operator precedence list in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence). In that list `||` operator has precedence number 5 and `==` has precedence number 10. So operator that has a higher precedence number will be evaluated first

If `s.charAt(c) == "B"` is `true` JavaScript engine will evaluate `true || "b"` that gives `true` as result.

If `s.charAt(c) == "B"` if `flase` JavaScript engine will evaluate `false || "b"` which gives result as `"b"`

So in side if condition coercion happens and `if ("b")` will act like  `if(true)` and all the characters will be counted.

**You can prevent this by using `s.charAt(c) == "B" || s.charAt(c) == "b"` insted of `s.charAt(c) == "B" || "b"`.**